# PHP: include file relative to calling file NOT root file?

Tags: php, include, php4, filepath

OK say I have a file called `fileA.php` in the same directory I have another file called `fileB.php`

so inside fileA there is this `require_once('fileB.php')` notice I did not specify a file path because both files are in the same directory.

Now if fileA is included into another file that is located somewhere else, it fails to include fileB because the parent file (the file that included fileA) is not in the same directory as fileB.

So how can I make it so that fileA loads fileB no matter where fileA is included into?

Does that make sense?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming both fileA.php and fileB.php are *guaranteed* to be in the same directory, this should work:

```
// fileA.php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'fileB.php')
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#78716

You can set the include root to your website root.